# Access for the path C:\ is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, path, save, html

if i save my webpage as html it is giving me the error:

Access for the path C:\ is denied -ftp.

in http locally it is working. it is storing in the desktop. but after publishing in ftp server it is showing this error

how to resolve this errror

Comment: This seems like a superuser question?  Or are you saving it via a program that you wrote?

Answer (score 1):

on Windows 7? you can turn off UAC.

Answer (score 0):

Below, I assume that the web application is not allowed to save data to the hard drive.

Make sure that the [process running the worker process for IIS](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101750&seqNum=6) has write permission for that folder. However, it is unusual to save files in C:\, and usually a web application should use a database server to store new data. If you deploy your web site to a hosting server, you might not be allowed to save data on the hdd of the server.